# Insert multiple rows using for loop

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to insert multiple rows into a table using for loop, but having some errors. What is wrong in this code?

```
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO pl_tbl (p_id,po_name,po_val) VALUES

            for ($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) 
            {
                ('$id','$data['data']['name_'.$i]','$data['data']['val_'.$i]')");
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Codeigniter active record has a function insert_batch i think that is what you need:

```
$data = array(
array(
  'p_id' => 'My id' ,
  'po_name' => 'My Name' ,
  'po_val' => 'My val'
),
array(
  'title' => 'Another title' ,
  'name' => 'Another Name' ,
  'date' => 'Another date'
)
);

$this->db->insert_batch('pl_tbl', $data);
```

Other way:

```
for ($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) 
  {
     $data = array(
      array(
      'p_id' => $id ,
      'po_name' => $data['data']['name_'.$i] ,
      'po_val' => $data['data']['val_'.$i]
     );
     $this->db->insert('pl_tbl', $data); 
  }
```

Comment: i got like this  INSERT INTO `pl_tbl` () VALUES (), (), ()

Comment: please use insert_batch function form CI

Answer (score 4):

Try it:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO pl_tbl (p_id,po_name,po_val) VALUES";
$values = [];

for ($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
    $values[] = "('$id','$data['data']['name_$i]','$data['data']['val_$i]')";
}

$sql .= join(',', $values);
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: then try `$values = array();`

Comment: Doesn't this accomplish him saving all his data in one row instead of multiple rows?

Comment: @rokas thanks, i now see it. Didn't not know you could send multiple rows like that

Answer (score 2):

try this simple code its should work for you..

```
<?php
  for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
  {
     $sql="INSERT INTO pl_tbl (p_id,po_name,po_val) VALUES ('$id','$data['data']['name_'.$i]','$data['data']['val_'.$i]')";
     $result = mysql_query($sql);
  }
?>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$data=array();
for ($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) 
{
   $temp=array();
   $temp['p_id'] = 'My id'; //actual value
   $temp['po_name'] = 'My Name'; //actual value
   $temp['po_val'] = 'My val'; //actual value
   array_push($data,$temp);
}
$this->db->insert_batch('pl_tbl', $data);
```

You can try with this code.

Comment: i updated my code. please try again. i hope it will be working.

Answer (score 0):

try to save the whole query in a variable and then run with the mysql_query should help you.

so code will be

```
$sql_query="INSERT INTO pl_tbl (p_id,po_name,po_val) VALUES ";

    for ($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) 
    {
        $sql_query.="('$id','".$data["data"]["name_".$i]."','".$data["data"]["val_".$i]."') ";
    }
$sql=mysql_query($sql_query);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this correctly, you should be doing this

```
for ($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
    $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO pl_tbl (p_id,po_name,po_val) VALUES  ('$id','".$data['data']['name_'.$i]."','".$data['data']['val_'.$i]."')");
}
```